# Undocumented "user_dim.user_properties.value.cleared" property in firebase events imported data in Bigquery intraday table

Tags: android, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

There is undocumented **"user_dim.user_properties.value.cleared"** property in firebase events imported data in the Bigquery intraday table (ANDROID events data set).
As you can see, there is no such property in schema https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en 
But we have it (see screenshot).[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmQFY.png)
It appeared a few days ago when Android client started adding to the event some user properties (custom and predefined such as user_id)
Thus, I can't UNION the tables to analyse both IOS & ANDROID events as a single dataset because they have different schemas.

Why did it appear? Can I exclude it from the schema in Android SDK (or some another way) without a necessity to modify my SQL query?